# How to read csv values which contain pound character using PHPExcel?

Tags: csv, phpexcel

I have a csv file with some cell values contain pound character. When i read it using PHPExcel, it returns blank value for those cell values. Any solution?
Below is the code i am using currently:

```
$path='test.csv';

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($path);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($path);
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);

 $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(34, 2);
        $val = $cell->getValue();
        echo $val;
```

Below is the var_dumping or $cell variable:

```
object(PHPExcel_Cell)[243]
private '_value' => boolean false
private '_calculatedValue' => null
private '_dataType' => string 'b' (length=1)
private '_parent' =>
object(PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorage_Memory)[9]
```

Comment: Is anyone facing same issue?

Comment: A pound sign is simply a normal string character, no different to any other string character, so PHPExcel should load it in exactly the same way it will load any string value..... please provide some sample code/file to show how you are reading and testing the values in the file

Comment: If you need these strings converting to a number, then you'll need to use the advanced value binder, which should then treat them as numbers for storing in the cell, but apply a money format mask to the value

Comment: Added current code  @MarkBaker

Comment: So the cell at column 34 row 2 definitely has a value? Note that 34/2 corresponds to address AI2. What do you get if you try var_dumping $cell? It's difficult to say what is going on without a copy of the file, so you'll have to do a lot of debugging to see what's happening

Comment: Do anyone know solution?

Comment: Well the dumped value that you've provided tells me that PHPExcel is reading the data as a Boolean with a value of false, and that's what it's telling you..... what I can't prove (because I don't have access to your file) is that cell AI2 actually is a Boolean false in your file (not a blank as you suggest)..... but PHPExcel doesn't generally lie about such things.... are you accessing the correct cell?

Comment: Try using `echo $cell->getCoordinate();` to verify that you're really accessing the cell that you believe you're accessing

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, the coordinates are correct, i have also verified entering other value in same cell.

Comment: I believe that `$cell->getValue()` function returned false because it could not read the value successfully.

Comment: Please provide the evidence to back up that supposition, because your var_dump of the $cell object tells me otherwise.... The value is specifically defined in the cell `private '_value' => boolean false` as is the datatype `private '_dataType' => string 'b' (length=1)` (`b` for `Boolean`).... if a value can not be read properly, then I would expect a NULL to be returned

Comment: Anyways, the value is read as blank, you can try running same code. @MarkBaker

Comment: I have tested it, running the same code that you've posted here, and I get exactly what I expect to get, a string containing "£123,457.78".... what I can't do is test it using your data, but PHPExcel is working exactly as I'd expect it to work

Comment: If you're certain that there is a bug in PHPExcel itself, then I'm afraid you'll have to debug it yourself, because I cannot recreate the situation that you're getting, and if I can't recreate a bug it's almost impossible to fix it

Answer (score 0):

For any one else with this issue, it turned out to be an encoding issue on the reader. This pointed me to the correct solution.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/360